# Jumped off the balcony to a tree house/Jumped from the balcony to a tree house

Tags: sentence-choice

1. The boy jumped off the balcony to a tree house.
2. The boy jumped from the balcony to a tree house.

His intention with the jump is to reach the tree house, which is on a height level with the balcony.

Are both the suggestions fine? Do you have a better one? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To “jump off” something implies jumping and then falling, to the ground is implied unless stated otherwise. When jumping “to” another thing, you would use “jumped from X to Y”.